# css is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, web

The faulty line is here :

```
var f = parseInt($("#" + a + "kinetic")
    .css("height")
    .replace("px", ""));
```

With IE8, weird thing is that the error doesn't pop up when running the website localhost but it does when we publish it and access it on the published server.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using any libraries other than jQuery, such as moo tools, prototype, etc.

Comment: Why not simply using `var f = $("#" + a + "kinetic").height();`?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery correctly? Does changing `$` to `jQuery` work?

Comment: On a side note, you should be sure to pass the radix to parseInt. It will prevent unexpected behavior in the parsing.

Comment: Don't `replace` "px", it is pointless as you are `parseInt`ing the string. If you use `parseInt`, then always use a radix.

Comment: What is `a`? Are you sure the element `$("#" + a + "kinetic")` exists? There is no need in `replace` here. Just use: `var f = parseInt($("#" + a + "kinetic").css("height"), 10);`.

Comment: Does the code you have appear below the elements you are selecting on or in the HEAD on .ready()?

Comment: Look at the error. the css method doesn't exist on $(), this means $() != jQuery() right?

Comment: Okay, I replaced my code with this var f = $("#" + a + "kinetic").height(); . But now a new error pop ups : in chrome the error is defined like this : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined. The line affected is this :  if ($("#" + a + TableWeekTag)
        .css("width")
        .replace("px", "") < 1255) {
        $("#" + a + "SmallScrollDiv")
            .width(c)

Comment: @TommyLeblanc What does `alert($.fn.jquery)` give you.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be so?

```
var f = parseInt($("#" + a + "kinetic")
    .css("height"));
```

or

```
var f = parseInt($("#" + a + "kinetic").height());
```

Comment: Tried both, same error poppin' Still, it works when running localhost but when published, i get the same error.

Comment: It really sounds like $() isn't jQuery in your environment.

Comment: Have you something like firebug? Then you can see if your javascripts can be found. maybe something is missing there?

Comment: Okay, I replaced my code with this var f = $("#" + a + "kinetic").height(); . But now a new error pop ups : in chrome the error is defined like this : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined. The line affected is this : if ($("#" + a + TableWeekTag) .css("width") .replace("px", "") < 1255) { $("#" + a + "SmallScrollDiv") .width(c)

Comment: Replace ` if ($("#" + a + TableWeekTag) .css("width") .replace("px", "") < 1255)` with ` if ($("#" + a + TableWeekTag) .width() < 1255)`

Comment: It's really complicated to understand your aim. Check out http://api.jquery.com/offset/ to see how to use it.

Comment: @PKeidel Replaced with it, new error pops up : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null -!- The line is : .offset({ top: b.offset() .top - 2, left: b.offset() .left }) The error pops out on line .top -2

Comment: Why does everything works localhost and bugs when published ? That's my main concern.

Comment: I don't know. Could it be possible that you use different jQuery versions?

Comment: What do you mean, I publish the web site with VS2008 and that's about it. I mean, the "publish" action uploads the localhost jQuery  to the published server, no ?

Comment: Have you tried it with "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>" instead of a local one?

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough :

```
var f = jQuery("#" + a + "kinetic").height();
```

as `height()` return an int, if you want to get the actual height of an element.

Note that if your element hasn't the height css property set before, even it has height, `jQuery(".element").css("height")` will return null.

There you can learn more about `.height()` http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: It worked but another error poppep up, see previous comments, thanks :)